# AngularJS: Cannot find the reason for the following error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to `AngularJS`, just started to learn it like 30 mins ago and trying to practice with some basics to get going. I saw the similar posts with the same error, but could not find the solution.

I have a simple html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="../Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
      <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button> 
      <p ng-show="visible">Hello World!</p> 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And controller in app.js file:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.visible = true;

   $scope.toggle = function () {
      $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
   }; 
}
```

When loading the page I have the error in a question.

What can be wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define angular `module` first then add that components like  `controller`, `directive`, `factory`, etc. in it, then you need to add that module inside the `ng-app` directive.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
      <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button> 
      <p ng-show="visible">Hello World!</p> 
   </div>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.visible = true;
   $scope.toggle = function () {
      $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
   }; 
};
```

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kqQRTnGXVIgidvCKZWWt?p=preview)